# Pandas replace from dictionary and regex not working

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dictionary, replace

I am noticing a strance bahavior in the pandas replace function when trying to pass a dictionary with dictionaries as so:

```
mutual_format = {'col1' : {'(?i)o':'0', '[^\d)]':''},
                  'col2' : {'name ':''}}

df.replace(mutual_format, regex=True)
```

In this case, the col 2 replacement works, however th first one is completly ignored.
What am I doing wrong?

```
col1             |   col2
0004564321 / O       name asdfg asd as
00045632145 / O      name bla bla
00045632145           name asdf asdf
```

Comment: Is the DataFrame that you're showing the original frame? Or after your transformation? The desired result? Or the actual result?

Comment: It works on my end, Col1 after replacement is `00045643210, 000456321450, 00045632145` - Pandas version 0.24.2.

Comment: WOMM as well. `pd.__version__ # '0.24.1'`

Comment: @Mike, that is the dataframe I am tranforming

Comment: Interestingly enough, this works for on 0.24.2, however, it does not on 0.24.1 for me. So an !pip install --upgrade pandas was the solution for me